# How to set an executor for async-http-client?

Tags: java, asynchttpclient

How to setup the thread pool size for async-http-client? I found this - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html to create a thread pool. But I am not able to set the executor for the client. My connections are limited and hence I want to restrict the number of threads to only 10 in the thread pool. I am using async-http-client:2.12.3

```
final AsyncHttpClient http =
        asyncHttpClient(
                config().setThreadPoolName("CustomThreadPool"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
public AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient() {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); // create executor
    EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(10, executorService); // specify number of threads to be used by this instance and provide your executor

    DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder configBuilder = Dsl.config()
            .setEventLoopGroup(eventLoopGroup);

    return Dsl.asyncHttpClient(configBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. One question though. What's the difference between the first parameter to NioEventLoopGroup and the thread size in the executor. What happens if they are different?

Comment: Basically you create the thread pool executor with n threads. Then you specify the number of threads in eventloopgroup and provide your executor. It means that this instance of client will use exactly the number of threads that you specified. That's okay for sure if your executor has more threads than you specified in the eventloopgroup, but I'm not sure what would happen if the executor has less threads than you specified in the eventloopgroup.